# Typescript and requirejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, require

I have a factory module which use require to create the desired objects

```
getProviderManager(providername: string): VideoProviderManager {

    var providerManager = require(providername);
}
```

the VideoProviderManager is decalred as `

```
export class VideoProviderManager
```

However I have lots of errors that VideoProviderManager isn't known and 
I have tried `

```
import VideoProviderManager = require("VideoProvider/VideoProviderManager");
```

But without sucess. I am trying to use combination of require and export classes with namespace of a module
is it possible?`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export `VideoProviderManager` as the value of the module, you need to use the `export =` syntax:

```ts
class VideoProviderManager {
  // ...
}
export = VideoProviderManager;
```

Using `export class VideoProviderManager` means that the class will be exposed on the `VideoProviderManager` property of the module instead.

See [The Definitive Guide to TypeScript](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/12/31/definitive-guide-to-typescript/#imports-and-exports) for more detail on this.

Additionally, for `getProviderManager`, the synchronous require syntax you are using necessitates the module having already been loaded by RequireJS.

Comment: I have changed all my files to use export and import, and all the errors are gone, how ever when i call var providerManager = require(providername); i get exception that the module cannot be found, although i gave it obsolute path, i want to load those modules according to what the user decide to use

Comment: You need to use the asynchronous `require` call if you are trying to load an unloaded module. `require([ providername ], callback)`. Note the first argument is an array and the second is a callback that will be invoked once the module is loaded. No, there is no other way to do this where you can return the module value from your `getProviderManager` function.